# Why does Android FusedLocationProviderApi requestLocationUpdates send updates with weird keys?

Tags: android, android-fusedlocation, android-googleapiclient

I'm using com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.3.0. This did not happen with 6.5.

The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi.html#requestLocationUpdates(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient,%20com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) says:

> Location updates are sent with a key of KEY_LOCATION_CHANGED and a Location value on the intent.

Well, that much is true. It also sends updates with key:
com.google.android.gms.location.EXTRA_LOCATION_RESULT

and another update with key:
com.google.android.gms.location.EXTRA_LOCATION_AVAILABILITY

What are these for? Where are they documented?

Here's my code:

```
// Needed for all API calls
mClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
        .addApi(LocationServices.API)
        .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
        .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
        .build();
mClient.connect();

// Create the LocationRequest object
mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
// Use high accuracy
mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
// Set the update interval to 5 seconds
mLocationRequest.setInterval(5000);
// Set the fastest update interval
mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(5000);

Intent locationIntent = new Intent(this, LocationReceiver.class);

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    Intent locationIntent = new Intent(this, LocationReceiver.class);
    // Set up periodic location updates
    mLocationPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, locationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    mFusedLocationProviderApi.requestLocationUpdates(mClient, mLocationRequest, mLocationPendingIntent);
}
```

And then this is my LocationReceiver:

```
public class LocationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String TAG = "LocationReceiver";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger();  // this line is key
        Log.w(TAG, "received location!");

        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

        // Log intent details
        for (String key : extras.keySet()) {
            Object value = extras.get(key);
            Log.d(TAG, String.format("%s %s (%s)", key,
                    value.toString(), value.getClass().getName()));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's interesting, it's not documented at all.  I've always just used a listener, so I haven't seen what the PendingIntents look like.  Can you show your code?  I'd like to test this.

Comment: It's not documented, but it seems PendingIntent is invoked for https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationAvailability.html

Comment: What was the LogCat output for the class names?

Answer (score 0):

LocationAvailability delivers "Status on the availability of location data".

Google docs says:
"Delivered from LocationCallback registered via #requestLocationUpdates(GoogleApiClient,LocationRequest,LocationCallback,Looper) or **from a PendingIntent registered via #requestLocationUpdates(GoogleApiClient, LocationRequest, PendingIntent)**. It is also available on demand via getLocationAvailability(GoogleApiClient)."

Thats why you received location availability data.

Comment: Could you provide a link to that documentation?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationAvailability